# Remote Desktop to Windows Server in Azure: Your credentials didn't work

Tags: remote-desktop, window, azure

I have created a Windows server in the Azure cloud service, and after that, when I am trying to connect through Remote Desktop Client, it didn't work.

I get this message:

> Your credentials did not work

I searched this issue but can't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: What client version (OS version)? What server version? Is your machine domain joined? How do your credentials look like: contoso.com\testuser1 or something else? Did you look in eventvwr?

Comment: problem solved,with a restart

Comment: @cdavid how can i install xampp in it,and access from any network